# Unable to clone git repo using ansible

Tags: git, ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x

I just upgraded to ansible 2.2 (to get `systemd` task functionality not available in 2.1), and now I'm unable to clone my application repo.

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The play in question is:

```
- name: Checkout Django application
  become: no
  git: repo=git@bitbucket.org:myusername/application.git
       dest=/tmp/myapplication
       accept_hostkey=True
```

I've enabled host key forwarding (as I said, this play was working previously). `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org -i $HOME/.ssh/my_ssh_key` works.

Here's the verbose output:

```
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/core/source_control/git.py
<111.222.333.444> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deploy
<111.222.333.444> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/me/.ssh/my_ssh_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=deploy -o ConnectTimeout=10 111.222.333.444 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480328606.84-68734816115955 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1480328606.84-68734816115955="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480328606.84-68734816115955 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<111.222.333.444> PUT /tmp/tmpRIvaKP TO /home/deploy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480328606.84-68734816115955/git.py
<111.222.333.444> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -vvv -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/me/.ssh/my_ssh_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=deploy -o ConnectTimeout=10 '[111.222.333.444]'
<111.222.333.444> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deploy
<111.222.333.444> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/me/.ssh/my_ssh_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=deploy -o ConnectTimeout=10 111.222.333.444 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/deploy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480328606.84-68734816115955/ /home/deploy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480328606.84-68734816115955/git.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<111.222.333.444> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deploy
<111.222.333.444> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/me/.ssh/my_ssh_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=deploy -o ConnectTimeout=10 -tt 111.222.333.444 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python /home/deploy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480328606.84-68734816115955/git.py; rm -rf "/home/deploy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480328606.84-68734816115955/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Edit: downvote? Feel free to comment on any ambiguity in the question so that I may fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow during my control machine upgrade (during which I upgraded Ansible), I deleted the relevant key entry from ssh agent. Confirmed with:

```
ssh-add -L
```

And added the key back with:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_ssh_key
```